# casting type in methods in java

Tags: java, casting

what is wrong with this piece of code?
consider building an ArrayList containing all buildings and
Building is superclass for Farm and StoneMine:

```
public Building returnBuilding(int i)
{
    if(buildings.get(i) instanceof Farm)
        return (Farm)buildings.get(i);
    if(buildings.get(i) instanceof StoneMine)
        return (StoneMine)buildings.get(i); 
    else
        return null;
}
```

then if i call

```
returnBuilding(1).SOMEMETHODEJUSTINFARMCLASS();
```

which `building.get(1)` is an instance of Farm class,
i get a run time error

Comment: This does not compile, does it?

Comment: what is the runtime error?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. How is "buildings" declared?

Comment: You probably get a compile error rather than a runtime error, don't you?

Comment: an else or another return would be cool in the returnBuilding method.

Comment: You only return when the buildings are GoldMine and StoneMine, not when it is a Farm

Comment: it says: that method(SOME...) is not defined in type Building

Comment: @hamon it has been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`returnBuilding` returns a `Building`, not a `Farm`. Casting `game.buildings.get(i)` before returning does not change that.

If the runtime class of `game.buildings.get(i)` is `Farm`, cast the return value of `returnBuilding` to `Farm` before calling the `SOMEMETHODEJUSTINFARMCLASS` method.